# Include arithmic operation in mongodb projection builder using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is it possible to include an arithmic operation, eg. `$multiply`, in a projection builder using C# and the `Builders` class.
Something like:

```
var projection = Builders<MappingClass>.Projection
                .Include(**multiply property in MappingClass with value**)
```

I know this can be done using BsonDocument, eg.

```
new BsonDocument("$project", 
    new BsonDocument {                  
        { "value", new BsonDocument("$multiply", new BsonArray{ "$value", multiplier })
    }
)
```

I would like to do this using the Builders class.
If this is possible, i can then do:

```
var documents = collection
    .Find(filter)
    .Project<MappingClass>(projection)
    .ToList();
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I find it much easier to use the `.AsQueryable()` extension in order to use LINQ.
Second, the intention of this question was to perform an arithmetic operation when the data is extracted from MongoDB. I find it much easier to perform this arithmetic operation when data have been loaded, and not when I’m loading it.
I guess I was doing a micro-optimization.